# Risc-V input output use

Tags: riscv

I m triying to do a bigger number printer with risc-v. But i cannot implement that. What is not going in my code?[image]

Comment: Bigger than what?  Though, I have to say I don't get how that code applies.

Comment: I mean, I want give 2 input and it should output the biggest integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find some exemple for risc-v input and output exemple for beginner.
[image]

Comment: Please don't give code as image.